# How to convert touch coordinates from float into int?

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I would like to find out how can I convert touch coordinate that I get in float form to an integer. I am pretty new to java programming and android. I want to define a rectangle around my touch area and then use something like this:

```
    Rect touchArea = new Rect();   //I have only float coordinates to define this rect
    Rect predefinedRect = new Rect(); //This rect is defined with integers
    if(touchArea.intersect(predefinedRect)){
        //do something
    }
```

Also there isn't method like Rect(RecF), at least I haven't found one. So what could I do to use that .intersect() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a RectF constructor that takes a Rect. So you could use that and then use the intersect in the RectF class.

If you want to convert float to int you could just do

```
int i = (int)1.5;
// i = 1
```

but be careful with how the float just gets cut and not rounded.

Comment: Ok, then how does android's coordinate system looks? As I understand, the center of the screen is (0,0) and then it goes to 1 to all sides. Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know the answer of your last questions. And this is not really a forum so you shouldn't ask unrelated questions in the comments. If you really can't find the answer(but you will), post another question.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to get the integer part of an float you can cast like:

```
float a = 1.2;
int b = (int) a;
```

this will make b to have the value 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to round, which you probably should since you're talking about touch coordinates, you should use MATH.ROUND()